# To connect to remote linux system using Runtime.exec with Putty private key

Tags: java, linux, remote-access

I wanna programmatically (using Java's Runtime.exec) open Putty on my system and connect to a remote linux system. Is there any syntax to pass Putty private key to the method runtime.exec and connect successfully. I am getting "Access Denied" error on the remote system if I just pass the username and pass-phrase and try to connect.

Comment: Long time since I had to use putty but iirc you can specify a profile/session to use on the commad line. So you would need to configure the profile/session for putty first in it's ui or command line config, then add the switch to select profile to your putty command string you pass to exec..

Comment: Thanks that works..but is there any way I can use a programmatically created session... I can create a session using JSch because I need a interface..i need java to interact with Linux box programmatically.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by your comments that you are trying to actually run some commands on a linux server, like

```
find /some-directory/ -type f -ecec grep -Hnw this-word {} ";"
```

via bash or other shell as opposed to rcp.

If yes then stop using putty, that is an interactive client for you to login to a remote server and interact with the connected shell.

I would suggest that you would be far better off using something like jssh, assuming it is still a current library.

With that you get fine control of the interaction flow with the remote server and iirc it supports private/public keys.